# Como remover elemento de uma list?

Tags: c++

Tenho uma lista de objetos da classe No, e gostaria de remover um objeto dessa lista, eu utilizo a biblioteca `list`.

Eu sei da existência do `pop_back()` e `pop_front()`, porém eles excluem exatamente o primeiro ou o ultimo item da lista. No meu caso eu terei uma lista de objetos dessa classe nó, e cada objeto tem o seu id, por exemplo: no1(id=1),no2(id=2),no3(id=3),no4(id=4)...

Eu gostaria de remover o id=2 por exemplo, como faria?

Segue minha classe No.h:

```
#ifndef NO_H_INCLUDED
#define NO_H_INCLUDED

#include <list>
#include "Aresta.h"

using namespace std;

class No
{
    int id;
    list<Aresta> *adjNo;

    public:
    No(int id); // construtor
    int getId();
    list<Aresta>* getAdjNo();
    void inserirAdj(Aresta aresta);
};

#endif // NO_H_INCLUDED
```

No.cpp:

```
#include "No.h"
#include <list>

No::No(int id){
    this->id=id;
    this->adjNo = new list<Aresta>;
}

int No::getId(){
    return this->id;
}

list<Aresta>* No::getAdjNo(){
    return this->adjNo;
}

void No::inserirAdj(Aresta aresta){
    adjNo->push_back(aresta);
}
```

Como seria a função para realizar a exclusão?

```
void No::excluirNo(int id){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Quando eu respondi a pergunta era diferente, não acho que ainda tenha informações suficientes para uma resposta diferente desta.

Não sei qual é a intenção deste código, mas partindo do inserir que é um simples `push_ back()`, acho que está procurando pelo [`pop_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/pop_back).

[Todos os membros da classe](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Alguns [algoritmos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) podem ser úteis. Assim como [iteradores](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator).

Comment: Eu simplifiquei todo o meu código para não poluir a pergunta. Eu sei da existência do pop_back() e pop_front(), porém eles excluem exatamente o primeiro ou o ultimo item da lista. No meu caso eu terei uma lista de objetos dessa classe nó, e cada objeto tem o seu id, por exemplo:
no1(id=1),no2(id=2),no3(id=3),no4(id=4)...

Eu gostaria de remover o id=2 por exemplo, como faria?

Comment: Sei que existe também o remove na biblioteca list, porém não sei como usar já que meu parâmetro é uma classe, não mais um inteiro...

Comment: O que você colocou na pergunta indicava que você queria outra coisa. E com o que tem lá eu não sei nem qual [e seu real problema. Eu respondi o que dava pelo que foi perguntado. Fica complicado você escrever uma coisa e querer outra.

Comment: Me desculpe se não fui claro, com o que complementei é possível me ajudar com algo ?